# Rendering a "Slice" of a Sphere in Java - Efficiency

Tags: java, performance, opengl, rendering, polygons

I'm attempting to render a hemisphere in java.  However, I'm wanting to render the slice that is defined by 2 angles - Azimuth and Elevation.  Since I'm defining a slice, I cannot (to my knowledge) use any built in primitives.  If the azimuth range is defined 0-360 and the elevation range is defined as 0-70, this will be a hemisphere with an upside-down cone-shaped hole in the top.

When rendering this inside "cone", I have chosen to do it as triangles in 5 degree increments.  This means that with a 360 degree cone, there are 73 different vertices (if I did the math correctly: 360/5degree slices with the origin or tip of the cone being shared with all sides, and all other vertices shared by adjacent triangle slices)

My question:
Is it more efficient to render these as a single polygon with with many vertices, or many triangles with only 3 vertices each.  If I do a single polygon, will I still have to include all three points for each triangle, or if it is a shared vertex, would I only include it once?  Sorry, my graphics rendering knowledge is limited.  Also sorry for being so verbose; I'm hoping someone may spot something erroneous in my thought process which may clear things up either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - Use Google to find an algorithm to create a sphere that is not a primitive.

Second - Somewhere down the chain - triangles will be used.  Most likely by the underlying library.  But for you - it depends upon whether or not you plan to chop up the created region.  If you are not going to subdivide the region further I would just make it one polygon.  Actually, after thinking about it for a second - you can always divide up the polygon afterwards too.  So just make it one polygon.

I thought about it some more and decided to amend this answer.  There are two ways you can create a polygon in openGL.  You can either create it as a triangular mesh or as an outline polygon.  So if you were asking "Should I use a triangular mesh or an outline polygon" I would say use the triangular mesh.  It is a lot easier to break up the triangular mesh than a polygon outline since, to break the mesh, all you have to do is to just stop at one of the points, include the last two points in the new object, and continue on down the triangular mesh.  An outline polygon requires you to go both left and right around the polygon to locate the two points where the break occurs.  If that is clear.  If not say so.

Update: 12:05pm
When making a polygon you can use a triangular mesh or a polygon outline.  The outline is mainly good for 2D whereas the triangular mesh works in both 2D and 3D systems.  If you have any kind of a polygon at all bigger than just three points then it is a good idea to put them all into an array.  This allows you to use the built-in routines that take an array and simply go through it to build your polygon.  By putting everything into an array you also make it easier on yourself to add new points or remove points or adjust points.  All you do is to change the array entry and then call the same routine to draw everything again. (Which should be just a single call to a function.)

Comment: OK, that is how I ended up implementing this (it was originally an outline polygon, but had many graphical issues - I think related to the improper order of the vertices).  So I'm guessing there isn't much, if any, efficiency hit by doing one or the other?  Assuming I only draw the shape once.  It does allow the user to modify the angles and will redraw everytime the user changes one of the numbers (each keystroke is considered a change, even if the user isn't done entering the number).  Is there a better way to do this without rebuilding the entire shape each time?

Comment: @Tam If you make the points along the polygon an array (which you should already be doing).  Then rebuilding the shape is as easy as just changing that one point and doing a redraw.  Because, compared to computers, people are like a snail - the fact that you are redrawing this one polygon each time should not matter.  If, on the other hand, you are redrawing the space station (which has over a million data points) - that would be different.  Then what you do is to allow the user to make any/all changes and just have a button they click to update the view. BTW - No - there isn't a better way.

Comment: @Tam : Don't forget.  If you like the answer or it is the correct one - give it a green checkmark. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  I didn't actually know I could checkmark an answer.  This site is so locked down at early stages of reputation, I can't even vote your answer up - only mark as correct.  Thanks again for your help, that really cleared things up for me.

Comment: @Tam : Glad I could help. :-)